# How to display the images of one form in another form using cache in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to display the images of one form in another form. I having two forms index.html and images.html. In index.html,

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> demo </title>   
    <style type="text/css">
        #container{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            postion:relative;
        }
        .divclass{
            height:auto;
            width:auto;
            position:relative;
        }
        .divclass #imgdiv1{
            margin-top:30px;
            position:relative;
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){                                   
            $('#imgdiv1 img').click(function(){         
                var n=$('#imgdiv1 img').length; 
                $('#lightboxdiv').append(' ('+n+')');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="#container">
        <div id="lightboxdiv">
            Light Box Images
        </div>
        <div class="divclass">          
            <div id="imgdiv1">
                <img src="001_19_3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:180px;position:absolute;visible:visible;z-index:1;">
                <img src="002_21_3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:180px;position:absolute;visible:hidden;">
                <img src="003_19_3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:180px;position:absolute;visible:hidden;">
                <img src="004_19_3.jpg" style="width:150px;height:180px;position:absolute;visible:hidden;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i click the images the image count will be 5. if i click the count, it diaplay the images in next window. I want to get the 5 images and display the images in, images.html. anyone can help? please!

Comment: you want to create an image gallery?

Comment: you re requirement is a bit not clear , mind to explore better

Comment: In a div there are 4 images. 1 image only visible in front. Others are hidden by the front image. If i click the image, it will display the count in another div namely count. If i click the div-count, it will display all the images that counted, in the new window. 

For example, I have div A = 5 images, div B = 4 images, div C = 3 images and so on. If i click div A, the count will be 5, if i click div A & B, count will be 5+4=9 and so on. If I click the div-count, it display all the images, that it was counted.(5/9/ so on).

Comment: Intriguing but totally impenetrable.

Answer (score 0):

ok... you can do this using querystring...
your index.html page look like this..

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

    .cont1
    {
        width:150px;
        height:80px;
        background-color:#bebebe;
    }

    img
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .ch:hover
    {
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count;
        var imgbox = [];

        $('.cont1').click(function () {

            var elem = $(this);

            if ($('.ch').html() == '') {

                count = elem.children('img').length;
                $('.ch').html(count);

                for (i = 0; i < elem.children('img').length; i++) {
                    imgbox.push(elem.children('img').eq(i).attr('src'));
                }
            }
            else {

                count = count + elem.children('img').length;
                $('.ch').html(count);

                for (i = 0; i < elem.children('img').length; i++) {
                    imgbox.push(elem.children('img').eq(i).attr('src'));
                }
            }

            elem.css('border', '2px solid #000');
            elem.unbind('click');
        });

        $('.ch').click(function () {
            window.location = "images.html?allimg=" + imgbox;
        });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="cont1">Div1
        <img alt="" src="Images/1.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
        <img alt="" src="Images/2.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
        <img alt="" src="Images/3.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="cont1">Div2
        <img alt="" src="Images/1.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
        <img alt="" src="Images/2.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
        <img alt="" src="Images/3.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
        <img alt="" src="Images/3.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="cont1">Div3
        <img alt="" src="Images/1.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
        <img alt="" src="Images/2.jpg" width="100px" height="70px" />
    </div>
    <br />
    Image Count : &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="ch"></span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and your images.html look like this..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location.toString();
        var img = url.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
        var imgcount = img.split(',').length;
        for (i = 0; i < imgcount; i++) {
            $('body').append('<img alt="" src="' + img.split(',')[i] + '" width="200px" height="140px" />&nbsp');
        }
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Explanation: we are using 3 divs with images in it. initially images are invisible by using css property display:none.
now after clicking the div it checks whether the count span is empty or not. if its empty it fill it with the no. of images present in the clicked div.
and at the same time we are using array. array will fill with the "src" of all images present in the clicked div and change the count number.

Or if count span is not empty  then it will add the no. of images present in the current clicked div and append the "src" of images in the array and increase the count no.

and on count click it fires a click event and we are using window.location = "index2.htm?allimg=" + imgbox . here we are using query string to transfer the array to next page.

Now on the images.html page
on document ready we are using $.split() to split the url and displaying the images on the page.

If you find any difficulty . let me know..
You can mail me @  amit.kishoreda@gmail.com